# Vega line chart with a single line

Tags: svg, charts, vega

How do you create a line chart in [Vega](https://vega.github.io) with just a single line?  There is an example provided by vega: https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/line-chart/ that has multiple lines.  The do not provide a single line example.

How do I change this example to only have one line? Is it in the `marks` section of the specification below?

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v3.0.json",
  "width": 500,
  "height": 200,
  "padding": 5,

  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "interpolate",
      "value": "linear",
      "bind": {
        "input": "select",
        "options": [
          "basis",
          "cardinal",
          "catmull-rom",
          "linear",
          "monotone",
          "natural",
          "step",
          "step-after",
          "step-before"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],

  "data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "values": [
        {"x": 0, "y": 28, "c":0}, {"x": 0, "y": 20, "c":1},
        {"x": 1, "y": 43, "c":0}, {"x": 1, "y": 35, "c":1},
        {"x": 2, "y": 81, "c":0}, {"x": 2, "y": 10, "c":1},
        {"x": 3, "y": 19, "c":0}, {"x": 3, "y": 15, "c":1},
        {"x": 4, "y": 52, "c":0}, {"x": 4, "y": 48, "c":1},
        {"x": 5, "y": 24, "c":0}, {"x": 5, "y": 28, "c":1},
        {"x": 6, "y": 87, "c":0}, {"x": 6, "y": 66, "c":1},
        {"x": 7, "y": 17, "c":0}, {"x": 7, "y": 27, "c":1},
        {"x": 8, "y": 68, "c":0}, {"x": 8, "y": 16, "c":1},
        {"x": 9, "y": 49, "c":0}, {"x": 9, "y": 25, "c":1}
      ]
    }
  ],

  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "x",
      "type": "point",
      "range": "width",
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "x"}
    },
    {
      "name": "y",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": "height",
      "nice": true,
      "zero": true,
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "y"}
    },
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "range": "category",
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "c"}
    }
  ],

  "axes": [
    {"orient": "bottom", "scale": "x"},
    {"orient": "left", "scale": "y"}
  ],

  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "group",
      "from": {
        "facet": {
          "name": "series",
          "data": "table",
          "groupby": "c"
        }
      },
      "marks": [
        {
          "type": "line",
          "from": {"data": "series"},
          "encode": {
            "enter": {
              "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "x"},
              "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "y"},
              "stroke": {"scale": "color", "field": "c"},
              "strokeWidth": {"value": 2}
            },
            "update": {
              "interpolate": {"signal": "interpolate"},
              "fillOpacity": {"value": 1}
            },
            "hover": {
              "fillOpacity": {"value": 0.5}
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You can't really rewrite the question once it has an answer in such a way that the answer is no longer valid. If you have more questions, ask them separately.

Comment: @RobertLongson yeah I wasn't really intending to change the question, just edited it too much.  My question about the y-axis is here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45812279/325727

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove some of the data. The "c":0 data forms one line, the "c":1 data the other. I've removed the "c": 1 data below.

```
 "data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "values": [
        {"x": 0, "y": 28, "c":0},
        {"x": 1, "y": 43, "c":0},
        {"x": 2, "y": 81, "c":0},
        {"x": 3, "y": 19, "c":0},
        {"x": 4, "y": 52, "c":0},
        {"x": 5, "y": 24, "c":0},
        {"x": 6, "y": 87, "c":0},
        {"x": 7, "y": 17, "c":0},
        {"x": 8, "y": 68, "c":0},
        {"x": 9, "y": 49, "c":0}
      ]
    }
  ],
```